# Is There a way to Handle popups in nightmarejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I need to handle site's popups window  in nightmarejs. I mean things like windows open list, close, scrape those created popups and maybe suscribe to popup creation event

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in the 2 mouth ago.
I think the nightmarejs cant do the  popups.
I used the spookyjs to slove this problem.

Comment: Thanks  i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of popups you're talking about.  For external windows, we're currently out of luck until [Electron #2605 is fixed](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2605).  For HTML flyovers, Nightmare should work fine.  For native popups - confirm, alert, etc - you'll need to take a look at defining your own [preload](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#custom-preload-script).